# Understanding the gem structure with Ruby and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am new to Ruby.  How useful is RVM? Should all gems eventually live under the RVM directory?

Comment: Closed for being "argumentative"!?!  S.O.'s self-aggrandized moderators are at it again...<sigh>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rvm is very useful since it allows you to have different ruby version installed and you can switch between them on the fly.
every ruby version will have its own gemset.
you can also have different gemset on the same ruby interpreter.

it is also very handy, since it does not overlap with the system interpreter. it is self contained in the .rvm directory in your home. if you screw it, just delete the directory and restart from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

RVM makes things much easier...especially with a development environment, like Ruby & Rails, that is CONSTANTLY changing. It's [easy to install](https://rvm.io). Do it now and don't look back.

And, yes, all your gems will be stored in folders within the `~/.rvm` directory

Answer (score 1):

The best pratice for gems in RVM is to create an gemset by application

```
rvm gemset create myappname
```

So all your gem for this app is in this gemset

for more information on location tape this command

```
gem environment
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers are wall well and good, but I think the most important aspect of rvm is the ability to have .rvmrc file.  This allows you to autoswitch to the gemset used in the particular project, which is great for open source projects where there is a particular set of gems used.